# Remove characters from items within lists that are inside a list

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list looks like below. I got the list from scraping and I need to get rid of those `<h5>` & `</h5>`. Is there a way to do that or do it on the run during scraping?

```
[[<h5>Tomato Street Grill</h5>, <h5>Go Live</h5>, <h5>Bistro</h5>, <h5>Fresh Inspirations</h5>, <h5>Harvest Bakery</h5>], [<h5>Tomato Street Grill</h5>, <h5>Go Live</h5>, <h5>Bistro</h5>, <h5>Starch Bar</h5>, <h5>Saucey</h5>, <h5>Pacific Fusion</h5>, <h5>Fresh Inspirations</h5>, <h5>Harvest Bakery</h5>], [<h5>Tomato Street Grill</h5>, <h5>Bistro</h5>, <h5>Go Live</h5>, <h5>Saucey</h5>, <h5>Pacific Fusion</h5>, <h5>Fresh Inspirations</h5>, <h5>Harvest Bakery</h5>], [<h5>Tomato Street Grill</h5>, <h5>Go Live</h5>, <h5>Saucey</h5>, <h5>Fresh Inspirations</h5>, <h5>Harvest Bakery</h5>]]
```

Ps: I tried to do something like `find_next_siblings('h5').text` and python what I got before the .text is a list so I cannot extract the text in that way.

Pps: each sublist's type is bs4.element.ResultSet and every smallest item's type is bs4.element.Tag.

Comment: Why not just grab the text between the `<h5></h5>` pairs during a scrape? Can you show us your relevant scrape code and what you've tried so far to remove these?

Comment: @esqew I said I tried that in the Ps and because it's a list, I cannot do that.

Comment: Are you using `BeautifulSoup`? The data posted looks like `BeautifulSoup` element objects. If so, to remove the tags, simply run `[[i.text for i in b] for b in data]`.

Comment: @LouieLee I'll take your word for it, but not sure why the data being presented in a list format would prohibit you from extracting the inner text from a node.

Comment: @esqew one of the lines is locations_per_meal.append(main_content.find('h4',text=str(meal_pick)).find_next_siblings('h5').text) and I got the error "ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?". The only way it works is that I remove that .text and get that list in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
for sublist in main_list:
    for ele in sublist:
        ele = ele.get_text()
        ele.replace('<h5>', '')
        ele.replace('</h5>', '')
```

This will go through the main list and then iterate the sublists, then remove the unwanted h5 tags from the sublists. Hope this helps.

Edit, since these are beautiful soup objects, you need to call the text method, there are a few ways to do this.

Comment: I got "'NoneType' object is not callable" but I checked that ele's type is bs4.element.Tag.

Comment: I apologize, are the elements in the list not strings? the question doesnt have enough information

Comment: @LouieLee If you can elaborate on what the data type is of the elements in your sublist, or what library the object type is from I will gladly edit the answer to help out.

Comment: each sublist's type is bs4.element.ResultSet and every smallest item's type is bs4.element.Tag.